# Calculation sum of objects in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to auto calculate the sums of objects that are being fetched everytime I click a button that fetches the data but I'm not sure how to proceed with it.

Here's the script that fetches the datas everytime I click a button:

```
createTrade (zoneId, cycleId) {
  this.getTrade().then(trade => {
    let zone = this.zones.find(zone => zone.id === zoneId);

    zone.cycles.map(cycle => {
      if (cycle.id === cycleId) {
        return {...cycle, ...cycle.trades.push(Object.assign(trade, {
          account: this.accounts.find(acc => acc.id === this.form.accountId)
        }))}
      }
      
      console.log(this.trade.realizedPL);
      return cycle;
    });

    this.form = {
      accountId: "",
      tradeId: null
    };
  }).catch(() => {
    alert('Trade does not exist');
  });
},
```

And here are the objects that I'm able to pull. I'd like to add all the "realizedPL" everytime I fetch new datas by clicking the button.

[image]

English is not my first language so I'm sorry if it's really confusing. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of ways you could go about this, really depends on your use case

Comment: `computed property + Array.reduce` or `watch + Array.reduce` will be the approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). It would look something like this:

```js
const totalRealizedPL => data.reduce(
  (subtotal, item) => subtotal + item.realizedPL, // accumulator function
  0 // initial value
);
```

```js
// generate some data for demo purposes
const data = Array.from({length: 5}, () => ({ value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) }));

const sum = data.reduce((subtotal, item) => subtotal + item.value, 0);

console.log(sum);
console.log(data);
```